# How can I tell the difference between source and published .NET code?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, compilation, safe-publication

How can I tell the difference between source and published .NET code?

I am looking at some inherited code that I have not touched in about a year.  The original designer had me first publish locally before uploading the published code to the internet server.  Now I am looking a number of backed up source folders as well bas backed up published folders.  I should have done a better job at naming the folders, I guess.  Now I wonder: How can I tell the difference between source and published .NET code?  Is there some easy way to see if some folder that contains only published code is lacking a file or xml setting?

Comment: Source is readable and published code is a binary. Not sure what you are asking.

Comment: Source should have lots of files with `.aspx` and `.aspx.cs` extensions, published should have `.aspx` and `.dll`.

Comment: If this is about deploying ASP.NET code, you should consider [precompiling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398860.aspx).  Precompiling will detect some errors like missing references, before you deploy.  You can also compile everything into a single assembly, and deploy that instead.

Comment: Voting to close because this is about process management, not programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As changes are made, they are published in the UI, so that means there should be some new files, or deleted files, and the directory tree may not be 100% the same.  What you could do is download the deployed code to your local machine, and use a tool like Beyond Compare or some other directory comparer and let it determine the markup changes for you.  There are several tools that do a good job for this.

That would give you an idea of the difference between files, but won't parse DLL's.  That you would have to use a tool like reflector or Telerik's JustDecompile to compare the code, but I really wouldn't go that far, but you could.